# Choosing cats, dogs and zebras - different approaches.

Tags: combinatorics

We have $10$ cats, $14$ dogs and $6$ zebras. Of these animals, we need to choose any $7$ provided we have at least $1$ cat, $2$ dogs and $3$ zebras.

A simple solution would be to choose the $6$ required animals from the required sets and then choose the last animal from a set of all the remaining animals (of which there are $30 - 6 = 24$.)

So, we get: ${10 \choose 1} * {14 \choose  2} * {6 \choose 3} * {24 \choose 1} = 436800$

The other approach involves identifying different ways of choosing, namely with 2 cats, 3 dogs or 4 zebras.

We get: $[{10 \choose 2} * {14 \choose  2} * {6 \choose 3}] + [{10 \choose 1} * {14 \choose  3} * {6 \choose 3}] + [{10 \choose 1} * {14 \choose  2} * {6 \choose 4}] = 168350 $

Which, if any, is correct, and why is the other wrong?

Comment: Edited that, thank you.

Comment: The first method overcounts since there is no way to distinguish between, e.g., choosing cat $C_1$ as the designated cat and then $C_2$ as the extra animal and the other way round.  The second method is good.